# include the export line its not throwing an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, redux

- I am facing a weird error
- when the server is running and I include the export line its not throwing an error and able to see the application...even it shows webpack is valid
  export { SportsTopPortion  };
- but after including this line and start the server again I am facing the error
  Error: Invariant Violation:
- i am using webpack,node and react
- since I am using webpack for build I am thinking the error will be due to webpack
- checked React code for errors there is no problem in syntax.
- can you tell me how to fix it..
- the reason I am using export is to write unit test case
- whole code and test code can be seen in gist below
  https://gist.github.com/js08/51e486aac90403a4946629f1d8bb985d
- I am debugging for past four days not able to find out

code snippet

```
export { SportsTopPortion };

export default connect(state => ({
    sportsAuthentication: state.template.sportsAuthentication,
    sportsPlayers: state.template.sportsPlayers,
    sportsUpperBar: state.template.sportsUpperBar
}))(SportsTopPortion);
```

error

```
ERROR: Command: 'node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js' failed with exit code 1: 'Current sports_enc: development
Using DEV build configuration
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite
C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\fbjs\lib\invariant.js:45
    throw error;
    ^

Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: obje
    at invariant (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\fbjs\lib\invariant.js:39:15)
    at instantiateReactComponent (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\instantiateReactComponent.js:64:134)
    at instantiateChild (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\ReactChildReconciler.js:29:28)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\traverseAllChildren.js:98:5)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\traverseAllChildren.js:114:23)
    at traverseAllChildren (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\traverseAllChildren.js:186:10)
    at Object.ReactChildReconciler.instantiateChildren (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\ReactChildReconciler.js:52:5)
    at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin._reconcilerInstantiateChildren (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\ReactMultiChild.js:197:41)
    at ReactDOMComponent.ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\ReactMultiChild.js:232:27)
    at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\ReactDOMComponent.js:591:32)
    at ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\ReactDOMComponent.js:479:29)
    at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:225:34)
    at [object Object].wrapper [as mountComponent] (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\ReactPerf.js:66:21)
    at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\ReactReconciler.js:37:35)
    at [object Object].ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (C:\sports-whole-package\node_modules\react\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:225:34)'
```

Comment: Can you copy the whole error ? Error: Invariant Violation:

Comment: @thangngoc89 hey updated...

Comment: well. It's a runtime error . not an syntax error.

Comment: @thangngoc89 can you tell me how to fix it.. and how did you find its run time error

Comment: Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite is a runtime error. 

I can tell you how to fix this if if you can provide a minimal reproduce.

Comment: @thangngoc89 i have give my whole code in gist...it hapeens when i include this line export { SportsTopPortion };

Comment: Your code in gist includes commented code and no hightlighting. Can't read that

Comment: And it should be `export SportsTopPortion;` only. You're not exporting an object

Comment: @thangngoc89 hey i have removed the commented code https://gist.github.com/js08/51e486aac90403a4946629f1d8bb985d

Comment: Did you try `export SportsTopPortion`. Also, looks like the issue is not in the current file

Comment: It's throwing syntax error if I remove curlies

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way, but with all that ES6 in there why not go all the way and do it like the docs say?

```
export class SportsTopPortion extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }...... all the rest of your code...

//note the use of React.Component not React.createClass
```

Or:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function() { ...
```

Not sure on this one:

```
export SportsTopPortion
```

Not at the bottom, at the top, where you create your React class

[Relevant Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes)

Comment: same invariant violation error happens when I use this method...anyother idea... `export class SportsTopPortion extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }...... all the rest of your code...`